# Git: How do I know if my open file is master or in a branch

Tags: git

Lets say I have a local repo with a .sql file. I currently have the .sql file open on my laptop.

I now create a new branch. The .sql file is still open on my laptop.

If I make changes to the .sql file how do I know if they will be saved to the master branch or to the new-branch?

Thanks

Comment: The changes are made to the branch you are currently at.

Comment: @B_CooperA I was on a local new-branch and added a new .sql file, however that file then appeared in both the new-branch and the master branch before merging. Does the same rule not apply when adding new files?

Comment: You only have 1 working folder (normally). You can't "save to a different branch". You can only save the file to disk, in your working folder. If you then add the changes (if there are any) and commit, that commit will be made on the branch you have currently checked out. Your question leads me to think you don't really understand how git works so my advice would be to run through some tutorials.

Comment: Thank you both for the explanations. I am still a little unclear though as I did not add or commit the new file to either branch, I just dropped it in the directory the repo is associated with and then when I listed the the contents of each branch the new file was in both branches.

Comment: I think you misunderstand what git is telling you. If you add a new file to your working folder and do `git status`, git will tell you the file is a new file. If you then check out a different branch, and then do `git status`, git will still tell you the file is a new file. The reason is that git has not started to track this file yet, so it just leave it be when you check out the other branch. As such, until you commit it on one of the branches, git will still keep telling you that you have a new file, but the file is not on either branch. Not until you commit it.

Answer (score 2):

Although the answer is written by @torek is in quite a detail. But to answer you quickly, I would say it depends on the conditions. Let us see those.

1. You are on the `develop` branch and `.sql` file open, you **did not** make any change to `.sql` file or any file under git invigilation and you created another branch out of `develop`.

   Well, in that case, you will switch to the new branch and all the new commits will go into your new branch.
2. You are on the `develop` branch and `.sql` file open, you made changes to one or more than one file(s) (which may include your `.sql` file) under git invigilation staying on the `develop` branch and you created another branch out of `develop`.

   Well, in that case, while switching you will get ***error*** from git asking you to either commit your temporary changes or `git stash` those. You do any of these two, and then you are again free to move to your new branch. The new commits will be counted under your new branch.

**NOTE:** My explanation is just to make you understand the things in layman terms. Git works slightly differently when you deep dive into it. :)

Answer (score 1):

Files are, in a very important technical sense, not in *any* branch, in Git.  In other words, you're asking the wrong question.  You should be asking: *Which commit(s), if any, contain this file?*  You can then refine the question to *which commits contain exactly this version of this file* or *which commits have modified this file, as compared to their parent commit* and so on.

(I suspect that one of these answers right now is that *no* commit contains that file, or that version of that file, but you have not given us enough to go on here, for me to be sure.)

The way Git works is a bit sneaky:

- Git repositories store *commits*, not files.  Of course, each commit stores some files, so it's safe to say that Git stores files, right?  Well, sort-of-right, but this will [lead you down the garden path](https://www.merriam-webster.com/thesaurus/lead%20one%20down%20the%20garden%20path).  Try to think of commits as a sort of unit.  They're the unit-of-storage that you will work with, when you work with Git.
- The word *branch* itself is tricky: see [What exactly do we mean by "branch"?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25068543/1256452)
- The end result of all of this is that given a branch *name* like `master`, we have to first find one specific *commit*.  Then we can decide whether some version of some file is in that specific commit, or not.
- In any case, the files that are inside commits are all completely, totally, 100% read-only.  They're stored in a special format that only Git understands, and they're de-duplicated, because *every commit stores a full copy of every file!*  The de-duplication makes this OK.

When you're actively working with a repository, you start by doing:

```
git checkout master
```

or `git checkout` of some other branch name.<sup>1</sup> This checkout operation *copies* the frozen-format Git-only files out of some commit, expanding them into ordinary everyday files.

These ordinary everyday files go into a *work area* where you can work on them.  Git calls this work area your *working tree* or *work-tree*.<sup>2</sup>  The files you can see and work on/with are in this work-tree.  The work-tree is not part of the repository proper!  Changes you make here are *only* stored here.

Note that this work-tree is an ordinary set of files and folders, so *all* of your computer commands that work on such things, work on it.  This means you can create files that *aren't in Git at all* because they exist *only* in your work-tree, not in any commit.

Git makes new commits, not from the files that are in your work-tree, but rather from files that are stored in Git's *index*.  The index is a bit complicated and I won't go into any most of the details here, except to note that a `git checkout` fills in *both* Git's index *and* your work-tree from the commit you've selected.  This doesn't disturb any work-tree files that Git knows nothing about.  Again, such files *aren't in Git*.  They just exist in your work-tree.

If a file *is* in a Git repository, it's stored inside a commit, in the special frozen Git-only format.  Doing `git checkout` will extract that file, resulting in two more copies: one you *can't* see in Git's index, ready to go into the *next* commit,<sup>3</sup> and one that you *can* see and work on / with, in your work-tree.  When you have changed your work-tree copy, the updated file won't go into a new commit until you copy it back into the index, replacing the old index copy: that's what `git add` is for.

Git uses the phrase *untracked file* to mean *a file that is not currently in Git's index, but is in your work-tree*.  The `git status` command will show such files as *untracked*.<sup>4</sup>

---

<sup>1</sup>In Git 2.23 or later, you can use `git switch` here.  It does exactly the same thing—it's just been split out of `git checkout` as `git checkout` did at least two separate commands' worth of different jobs.  In Git 2.23, `git switch` does one job and `git restore` does the other one, instead of cramming both into `git checkout`.

<sup>2</sup>In Git 2.5 or later, you can add extra work-trees with `git worktree add`.  It's best to have Git 2.15 or later for this because of a pretty nasty bug that wasn't fixed until then.  (The bug only manifests if you leave an added work-tree around for at least two weeks, so if you have an old Git and want to use `git worktree add` for a quick fix, that's fine, just don't let it sit around for too long.)

<sup>3</sup>Technically, what's in the index isn't a literal *copy* of the file, but rather a *file name*, a *mode*, and an internal Git *object ID*.  But this only shows up if you dig into the index entries, using internal Git commands like `git ls-files --stage` and `git update-index`.

<sup>4</sup>To make `git status` shut up about these files, you can list them in `.gitignore`.  Note that listing a *tracked* file—one that *is* in Git's index—in `.gitignore` has no effect, though.